# jqmFlip directive - ng-model not showing up in controller (Angular with JQM)

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, angularjs

I have run into a problem using angular's JQM library. In particular, I am trying to use the jqmFlip directive to create a filter button.

When I add a ng-model attribute to the directive the data binding works fine in the DOM. But when I try to log the value of the ng-model from the controller it comes up as a blank string(because I have to define the ng-model like so:

```
$scope.search = {
 includeTags:"",
 includeKeywords:""
};
```

Otherwise the variable comes up undefined.

HOWEVER, I can log the correct values by calling $scope.$apply() before the log statement.

From what I understand, this isn't the best way to go about retrieving the value as I receive this error: $digest already in progress.

Any ideas as to why this is happening? I can post more code if necessary.

UPDATE: directive code

```
jqmModule.directive('jqmFlip', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/jqmFlip.html',
    scope: {
        onLabel: '@',
        onValue: '@',
        offLabel: '@',
        offValue: '@',
        mini: '@',
        disabled: '@',
        defaultValue: '@'
    },
    require: ['?ngModel', '^?jqmControlgroup'],
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrls) {
        console.log(ctrls);
        var ngModelCtrl = ctrls[0];
        var jqmControlGroupCtrl = ctrls[1];
        var parsedOn;
        var parsedOff;

        scope.theme = scope.$theme || 'c';
        scope.isMini = isMini;
        scope.onValue = angular.isDefined(attr.onValue) ? scope.onValue : true;
        scope.offValue = angular.isDefined(attr.offValue) ? scope.offValue : false;
        scope.defaultValue = attr.defaultValue;


        initToggleState();
        bindClick();

        function initToggleState () {
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(parseBoolean);
            parsedOn = parseBoolean(scope.onValue);
            parsedOff = parseBoolean(scope.offValue);
            ngModelCtrl.$render = updateToggleStyle;
            ngModelCtrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(updateToggleStyle);
        }

        function updateToggleStyle () {
            updateNaNAsOffValue(scope.defaultValue);
            var toggled = isToggled();
            scope.toggleLabel = toggled ? scope.onLabel : scope.offLabel;
            scope.onStyle = toggled ? 100 : 0;
            scope.offStyle = toggled ? 0 : 100;
        }

        // this has to be done in the change listener,
        // otherwise the potential scope value would be overwritten with the off value
        function updateNaNAsOffValue (defaultValue) {
            if (!ngModelCtrl.$viewValue) {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(defaultValue);
            }
        }

        function bindClick () {
            scope.toggle = function () {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(isToggled() ? parsedOff : parsedOn);
            };
        }

        function isToggled () {
            return ngModelCtrl.$viewValue === parsedOn;
        }

        function isMini() {
            return scope.mini || (jqmControlGroupCtrl && jqmControlGroupCtrl.$scope.mini);
        }

        function parseBoolean(value) {
            if (value === 'true') {
                return true;
            } else if (value === 'false') {
                return false;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
};
}]);
```

JQMcontrolGroup directive that is required by jqmFlip directive:

```
jqmModule.directive('jqmControlgroup', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/jqmControlgroup.html',
    scope: {
        mini: '@',
        iconpos: '@',
        type: '@',
        shadow: '@',
        corners: '@',
        legend: '@'
    },
    controller: ['$scope', JqmControlGroupCtrl]
};

function JqmControlGroupCtrl($scope) {
    this.$scope = $scope;
}
});
```

jqmFlip template URL:

```
angular.module("templates/jqmFlip.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
$templateCache.put("templates/jqmFlip.html",
"<div jqm-scope-as=\"jqmFlip\">\n" +
"        <label class=\"ui-slider\" ng-transclude></label>\n" +
"        <div class=\"ui-slider ui-slider-switch ui-btn-down-{{$scopeAs.jqmFlip.theme}} ui-btn-corner-all\"\n" +
"             jqm-class=\"{'ui-disabled': $scopeAs.jqmFlip.disabled,\n" +
"                        'ui-mini': $scopeAs.jqmFlip.isMini()}\"\n" +
"             ng-click=\"$scopeAs.jqmFlip.toggle()\">\n" +
"             <span class=\"ui-slider-label ui-slider-label-a ui-btn-active ui-btn-corner-all\" ng-style=\"{width: $scopeAs.jqmFlip.onStyle + '%'}\">{{$scopeAs.jqmFlip.onLabel}}</span>\n" +
"             <span class=\"ui-slider-label ui-slider-label-b ui-btn-down-{{$scopeAs.jqmFlip.theme}} ui-btn-corner-all\" ng-style=\"{width: $scopeAs.jqmFlip.offStyle + '%'}\">{{$scopeAs.jqmFlip.offLabel}}</span>\n" +
"                <div class=\"ui-slider-inneroffset\">\n" +
"                  <a class=\"ui-slider-handle ui-slider-handle-snapping ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-{{$scopeAs.jqmFlip.theme}} ui-shadow\"\n" +
"                     title=\"{{$scopeAs.jqmFlip.toggleLabel}}\"\n" +
"                     ng-style=\"{left: $scopeAs.jqmFlip.onStyle + '%'}\">\n" +
"                    <span class=\"ui-btn-inner\"><span class=\"ui-btn-text\"></span></span>\n" +
"                  </a>\n" +
"                </div>\n" +
"        </div>\n" +
"</div>\n" +
"");
}]);
```

jqmControlGroup template URL:

```
angular.module("templates/jqmControlgroup.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
$templateCache.put("templates/jqmControlgroup.html",
"<fieldset class=\"ui-controlgroup\"\n" +
"     jqm-class=\"{'ui-mini': mini, 'ui-shadow': shadow, 'ui-corner-all': corners!='false',\n" +
"     'ui-controlgroup-vertical': type!='horizontal', 'ui-controlgroup-horizontal': type=='horizontal'}\">\n" +
"    <div ng-if=\"legend\" class=\"ui-controlgroup-label\">\n" +
"        <legend>{{legend}}</legend>\n" +
"    </div>\n" +
"    <div class=\"ui-controlgroup-controls\" ng-transclude jqm-position-anchor></div>\n" +
"</fieldset>\n" +
"");
}]);
```

Reference in HTML:

```
<jqm-flip mini="true" jqm-theme="d" ng-model="search.includeTags" on-label="On" on-value="1" off-label="Off" 
         off-value="0" default-value="1"></jqm-flip>
          {{search.includeTags}}
```

Comment: Yes, create a Plunker or something, please. :)

Comment: @MichaelBenford I was not able to create a working jsFiddle or plunker...for some reason the directive would not render on the page. I have included the full code...I appreciate any help on this matter.